# Multiple mule-flow instances

Tags: mule

I have mule app with single mainFlow. Flow receives jms-message from MQ by *quartz:inbound-endpoint*, processes it and puts in another queue. Messages are independed. Is it possible to run multiple instances of my flow for concurrent message processing?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jRptQ.png)

Answer (score 0):

Yes. As long as your flow is neither transactional or two-way (request-response), you can set-up various asynchronous processing strategies.

You can add it either visually in the Studio in the flow's properties or by manually adding the attribute `processingStrategy="...yourStrategy"` to the flow's XML declaration.

For an in-depth guide to what everything means and does, see https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.8/flow-processing-strategies

Comment: The point of the question is a bit different. I added a scheme to edited text of the question to describe the desired process.